# Why do symmetric matrices have real eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products, symmetric-matrices

I am having a little bit trouble while understanding this theorem.

It says that: A symmetric matrix has real eigenvalues.

Proof. Extend the dot product to complex vectors by $(v, w) = \sum_i \bar {v_i}{w_i}$, where  $\bar {v_i}$  is the complex conjugate of $v_i$. For real vectors it is the usual dot product $(v, w) = v \cdot w$.

The new product has the property $(Av, w) = \left(v, A^{\mathrm T}w\right)$ for real matrices $A$ and $(\lambda v, w) = \lambda(v, w)$ as well as $(v, \lambda w) = \lambda(v, w)$.

Now $\lambda(v, v) = (\lambda v, v) = (Av, v) = \left(v, A^{\mathrm T} v\right) = (v, Av) = (v, \lambda v) = \lambda(v, v)$ shows that $\bar \lambda = \lambda$ because $(v, v) \neq 0$ for $v \neq 0$.

How do get this expression ($ \lambda <v,w>$)  because $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue if $AX = \lambda X$ and $(A-\lambda\mathbb{I}) = 0$?

Or in other words, how do we go from $(A-\lambda\mathbb{I}) = 0$ to $ \lambda <v,w>$?

How does this prove that $\lambda$ is real by showing that $\lambda = \bar \lambda$?

Comment: Is your question why $\bar \lambda = \lambda$ implies that $\lambda \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: When proving that $\lambda(v,v)=\overline{\lambda}(v,v)$, you forgot a conjugate in the last equality.

Comment: @Myridium yes ,

Comment: @LuaiGhunim because $a+bi=a-bi\implies b=-b\implies b=0$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that the eigenvalues of a real symmetric matrix are real](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354115/prove-that-the-eigenvalues-of-a-real-symmetric-matrix-are-real)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $\lambda = a + bi $ where $a,b $ are real numbers.  If $\lambda = \overline {\lambda} $, then $a + bi = a - bi $. Hence $2bi  =0$ and $b =0$. This shows that $a = \lambda \in \mathbb {R}$

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume

$$\lambda=a+bi\iff \bar\lambda=a-bi$$

thus

$$\lambda=\bar\lambda\iff a+bi=a-bi\iff b=0$$