# Do real eigenvalues $\implies$ symmetric matrix? And why is a positive definite matrix symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Proof:

$Av$ = $\lambda v$

$\implies \bar{v}^{T}Av = \lambda \bar{v}^{T} v$ ------(1)

And,

$Av$ = $\lambda v \implies \bar{A}\bar{v}$=$\bar{\lambda}\bar{v} \implies  \bar{v}^{T}\bar{A}^{T}=\bar{\lambda}\bar{v}^{T}$

$\implies \bar{v}^{T}\bar{A}^{T} v = \bar{\lambda}\bar{v}^{T} v$  ------(2)

Since $A$ has real eigenvalues, $\lambda = \bar{\lambda} \implies \bar{v}^{T}\bar{A}^{T} v = \lambda\bar{v}^{T} v$   ------(3)

Now, Assuming A is real ($A=\bar{A}$), and comparing equation (1) and (3):

$\bar{v}^{T}A^{T} v = \bar{v}^{T}Av$

Does that mean $A=A^{T}$?

And hence can I infer that a positive definite matrix (which of course has all eigenvalues real and positive) is symmetric? Is that the right reason behind it? If not, what makes a positive definite matrix symmetric?

EDIT: This question is not the same as "[Prove that the eigenvalues of a real symmetric matrix are real.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354115/prove-that-the-eigenvalues-of-a-real-symmetric-matrix-are-real)", but it actually asks about whether or not the converse it true.

Comment: @RodrigoPizarro This is **not** a duplicate of that question which is symmetric $\implies$ real eigenvalues. The OP is asking about the converse: does real eigenvalues $\implies$ symmetric.

Comment: Note that the term "positive definite" is often (but not always) used to mean "symmetric positive definite".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that the eigenvalues of a real symmetric matrix are real.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354115/prove-that-the-eigenvalues-of-a-real-symmetric-matrix-are-real)

Comment: @littleO Thanks. That was helpful. Actually I thought the same but just recently referred this link which confused me (page 2 para 1 line 2): https://www.math.utah.edu/~zwick/Classes/Fall2012_2270/Lectures/Lecture33_with_Examples.pdf

But now what u say is clear :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true. The following matrix $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$has real eigenvalues but is asymmetric. Also it is positive definite but this too **does not imply** symmetry.

Comment: Sorry this is not a good example of mon-symmetric matrix  has real eigenvalues. Infact this matrix is not diagonalizable! so no eigenvalues!!

Comment: @DrZafarAhmedDSc "so no eigenvalues" The number $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. A corresponding eigenvector is the vector $x = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @DrZafarAhmedDSc, do you believe that diagonalizability and existence of the eigenvalues are equivalent? In fact a matrix $A_{n\times n}$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$ **iff** the equation $Av=\lambda v$ holds for some vector $v$ and is diagonalizable only if its eigenvectors span the $\Bbb R^n$ or equivalently$$A=PDP^{-1}$$for some diagonal $D$ and invertible $P$.

Comment: @Mustafa Ayaz there are two things latent roots and eigenvalues they may be or may not be same. Your matrix has repeated latent roots but these are not  is not eigenvalues as your matrix is not diagonalizable. may. I have edited my solution in this regard.

Answer (score 6):

The question has been correctly answered by Mostafa Ayaz, but, just in case you suspect that the problem arises because his example isn't diagonalizable, here's a diagonalizable example:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2&-1\\0&1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The eigenvalues are $1$ and $2$, with eigenvectors $\binom11$ and $\binom 10$, respectively.

More generally, notice that, for a symmetric matrix, not only are the eigenvalues real but the eigenvectors for different eigenvalues are orthogonal. So you can produce many counterexamples like mine by just choosing some different real numbers to serve as eigenvalues and some non-orthogonal vectors to serve as eigenvectors.

Comment: Another easy way to produce counterexamples is to take real upper triangular matrices.  These will have real eigenvectors and real eigenvalues (namely the values along the diagonal), but are readily seen to be non-symmetric without citing any theorems or doing any computations beyond understanding row reduction and how to compute determinants (either via row reduction or via expansion by minors).