# Prove that this matrix cannot have complex eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This question was asked in my Linear Algebra assignment and I was unable to solve it.

---

> Let $a, b, c \in \Bbb R_{>0}$ such that $b^{2} + c^{2} < a < 1$. Consider the following $3 \times 3$ matrix $$A = \begin {bmatrix} 1&b&c\\b&a&0\\c&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ Prove that the eigenvalues of $A$ cannot  be non-real complex numbers.

---

I tried by using formula of trace= sum of eigenvalues  and that product of eigenvalues = determinant  but trace formula but that does not seem to help. Can anyone please tell how should i proceed.

Comment: Don't all real symmetric matrices have real eigenvalues?

Comment: @5Pack thank you !!!!

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/354115

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo If you have some spare time can you please have a look at this question asked by me . I shall be really thankful to you .https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3788633/a-quiz-question-based-on-matrices-on-complex-field