# A quiz question based on matrices over $\Bbb C$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying previous years questions of my linear algebra exam and I was unable to solve this particular question.

---

> State True/False with reasoning: Let $A$ belong to $M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{C})$. Then:
>
> 1. There exists a matrix $B$ belonging to $M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{C})$ such that $B^{2}=A$.
> 2. There exists an invertible  matrix  $P$ such that $PAP^{-1}$ is upper triangular.

---

For 1. I could think of comparing both sides but that is feasible for only $2 \times 2$ matrices.

For 2. I have no idea on which result I should use .

Any hints would be really appreciated .

Comment: For $2$, have you seen quotient spaces? Use the fact that every operator on a complex-vector space must have an eigenvector, quotient out by the space spanned by such eigenvector, and continue inductively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Consider $$A=  \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

If there exists $B$ such that $B^2=A$, then $B^4=A^2=0$, so $B$ is nilpotent, but $B$ has size $2$, so $B^2=0$, so $A=0$. This is absurd.

2. This is very classical, see for example : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Triangularisability

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. Consider what happens when you take determinants.
2. Have you ever come across Jordan Canonical Form?

Comment: We are given a generic $n \times n$ matrix, and asked if a square root always exists. Using that the determinant is multiplicative should guide towards straightforward counterexamples

Comment: But in point of fact the only such counterexamples are in some special instances of the case $\det A=0$.

Comment: Perhaps I require another coffee, but what if $A$ were to have negative determinant? The criterion you suggest seems unreasonable for any examiner to assume of their linear algebra students.

Comment: Yes, you're quite right. I won't delete my answer as I hope this discussion is useful. Hopefully you or another commenter can provide a clearer answer.