# How to find a basis of real eigenvectors for a real symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

While real symmetric matrices have real eigenvalues, their eigenvectors do not have to be real. If I am interpreting the conversation correctly, [THIS math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47764/can-a-real-symmetric-matrix-have-complex-eigenvectors) thread seems to suggest that it is, nonetheless, possible to choose a basis such that ALL of the eigenvectors are real. Is this true?

If so, how would I do this?

As a concrete example, I have a 448 x 448 real symmetric matrix. I compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors using MATLAB and 24 of the eigenvectors that it returns are complex, all the rest are real. How can I make these 24 complex eigenvectors real?

Comment: Eigenvectors are vectors, not real numbers.

Comment: @RickSanchez  real vectors = vectors whose entries are all real.

Comment: I see. I've never heard this term before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes: if $\lambda$ is a real eigenvalue of a real matrix $A$, there will be a basis of $\text{ker}(A - \lambda I)$ consisting of real eigenvectors.

I don't know why Matlab would return non-real eigenvectors for a real symmetric matrix.  Are you sure it's exactly symmetric, no asymmetry caused by roundoff error or other processes? nnz(A - A') returns 0?

Comment: You were right, it wasn't quite symmetric due to numerical errors. I corrected it and all of the eigenvectors returned are real valued. Thanks!